# Roaming profiles and network shares

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, roaming-profile

I have two servers, one is the DNS and DC and the other is the File Server. Both are running up to date versions of Windows Server 2008 R2.

First of all, I have created a folder called PROFILES and created a share on the file server:

[image: Network Share]

Then I have added the permissions (to try and troubleshoot) to allow everyone full read/write access to PROFILES:

[image: Permissions]

On the DC I have setup a test user account in my name with the following settings:

[image: User account with roaming profile]

but when I try and login to a test workstation I get a failure to access the profile error message.

Am I missing something? Both servers are connected to the same domain..

Comment: Start from the bottom up. Check the user can access \\oxygen. Then \\oxygen\profiles. Then\\oxygen\profiles\first.last. Usually by default the user that you created the profile will have exclusive access to that share, so you might test with the user first. Make sure you check both the NTFS permissions and the share permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the NTFS Permissions as set on the folder on your file server.

-Lewis

**EDIT:** Check the following post on Technet for best practice recommendations for configuring redirected folders and/or roaming profiles.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781907(WS.10).aspx#CommunityContent

The post by BipolarChucker (me) at the bottom of the page helps clarify a few settings.